# Ramifications of the psychic/CVE-2022-21449 ECDSA verification vulnerability

Tags: vulnerability, ecdsa

On 2022-04-19, Neil Madden [published](https://neilmadden.blog/2022/04/19/psychic-signatures-in-java/) a vulnerability in the ECDSA signature verification code of the library bundled with some editions of Java, including [some](https://neilmadden.blog/2022/04/25/a-few-clarifications-about-cve-2022-21449/) recent by Oracle and in [OpenJDK](https://openjdk.java.net/groups/vulnerability/advisories/2022-04-19). That became [CVE-2022-21449](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-21449) (I've yet to understand if [CVE-2022-21476](https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-21476), which goes back to Java 7, is related).

In a nutshell, action 1 of the [ECDSA signature verification procedure](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsubsection.4.1.4) is not performed correctly, and the rest is implemented such that the ***(0, 0)*** signature always verify.

I ask related questions

1. Are there implementations botched such that other signatures determinable from curve parameters always pass? I'm thinking in particular of ***(u⋅n, v⋅n)*** for some integers ***u*** and ***v***, possibly negative for signatures with ASN.1 decorum.
2. What are affected applications? I 'm thinking of

   - digital certificates: are there vulnerable PKI *and* ECDSA certification keys in their chain of trusted public certification keys?
   - code signing: are there vulnerable code verification gear *and* code signing certificates with ECDSA public key?
   - document validation, e.g. signed PDF: is any end-user application vulnerable? For these, there is profusion of certified ECDSA public key.

Comment: I know of at least one huge IoT deployment in France where the ANSSI KoolAid was drunk and where ECDSA sigs are a cornerstone of the security posture. (email in bio)